# Adding additional markup to leaflet marker?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to customize the html output for my leaflet markers. Specifically, I'm trying to assign them additional data attributes to trigger bootstrap modals based on an ID pulled from the database like this:

```
<div class="leaflet-marker-pane" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal-<?php some id from php(); ?>"
```

But I'm struggling as to how to attach the additional html.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add those to the entire markerPane? Or just on the markers within it?

Comment: Sorry, just the markers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to trigger a specific modal on click of a specific marker there is a much easier way to this instead of doing it declaritively like you're proposing now. You can just use the `click` event of `L.Marker` and call a specific modal whose ID you've added to the marker upon initialization. An example:

```
// Create a new marker
new L.Marker([<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lng; ?>], {

    // Add id to marker as an option
    id: <?php echo $id; ?>

// Attach to click event
}).on('click', function (e) {

    // Call modal with id
    $('#modal-' + this.options.id).modal('show');

// Add marker to map
}).addTo(map);
```

Here's more on handling bootstrap's modal via JS instead of data-attributes:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript

I even wonder if doing it the way you propose is going to work because bootstrap (i assume you're using bootstrap) will scan the page upon initialization for the data attributes which at that time aren't present on the markers yet. You can try if you want to, you'll need to add the data attributes to the marker's icon using the dataset property:

```
var marker = new L.Marker([<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lng; ?>]).addTo(map);

marker._icon.dataset.toggle = 'modal';

marker._icon.dataset.target = 'modal-<?php echo $id; ?>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, haven't tested the php bit, but it works flawlessly!

Comment: Couldn't test the PHP part myself, been years since i've really done anything PHP but the principal of the matter should be correct. :)